# maven javadoc generation issue of viewing on local tomcat server

Tags: view, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have managed to generate javadocs for my maven java project. 
I use the following in

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I use the goal javadoc:javadoc when building.

Is there a way I can start my tomcat server and view the generated javadocs via a URL on my tomcat server? Something like localhost:8080/...

Thanks